# asp .net mvc routing url with custom literal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Is it possible to make url with custom literal separator that can have default parameters ?

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Forums_links",
            "Forum/{forumId}-{name}",
            new { area = "Forums", action = "Index", controller = "Forum" },
            new[] { "Jami.Web.Areas.Forums.Controllers" }
        );
```

I have this as you see im using to dash to separate id from name so I can have url like:

```
/Forum/1-forum-name
```

Instead of:

```
/Forum/1/forum-name
```

I see the problem is I'm using multiple dashes. And routing engine don't know which one to separate. But overalll it doesn't change my question because I want to use multiple dashes anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question.

The only way I could come up with is much like Daniel's, with one extra feature.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Forums_links",
    "Forum/{forumIdAndName}",
    new { area = "Forums", action = "Index", controller = "Forum" },
    new { item = @"^\d+-(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-)*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" } //constraint
    new[] { "Jami.Web.Areas.Forums.Controllers" }
);
```

That way, the only items that will get matched to this route are ones formatted in the pattern of:

```
[one or more digit]-[zero or more repeating groups of string separated by dashes]-[final string]
```

From here you would use the method Daniel posted to parse the data you need from the forumIdAndName parameter.

Comment: +1 Good idea to constrain the sub-values, especially the Id. I would write that regex like `^\d+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$` which is a bit shorter, and matches URLs where the Id is present but the name isn't (alla StackOverflow). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this could be by combining id and name into the same route value:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Forums_links",
            "Forum/{forumIdAndName}",
            new { area = "Forums", action = "Index", controller = "Forum" },
            new[] { "Jami.Web.Areas.Forums.Controllers" }
        );
```

And then extract the Id from it:

```
private static int? GetForumId(string forumIdAndName)
{
    int i = forumIdAndName.IndexOf("-");
    if (i < 1) return null;

    string s = forumIdAndName.Substring(0, i);

    int id;
    if (!int.TryParse(s, out id)) return null;

    return id;
}
```